# How can I format a grid of cells based on another grid of cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, colors, formatting

it's my first question on Super User. I'm currently working with two (almost) identical Excel grids (the values differ). And I'm asking about whether it's possible to format a group of cells based on another group. In a way, it's like a formula but it's to do with colors.
Now, before you mark this question as a duplicate, this is NOT about conditional formatting, which is based on values. Here, it's simply something like this:
I have a group of cells A3-D15. Some cells are colored blue, some orange, some red, some green and I'd like to color another group of cells A19-D33 that same way. Here's what I mean:
orange red   red   red
blue   green green green
blue   green green green
...

I'd like to reuse this schema across multiple tables. How might that work? All my searches resulted in only articles about conditional formatting based on values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your first grid and press Ctrl + C to copy it.

Then right click the top left cell on your second grid and paste the formatting.

See selection in the image below.

[image]

Then repeat process for you other tables.

IF you had 100s of tables (grids) to copy to you could record the actions as a macro.

Comment: Thanks so much it worked!

Comment: @expressjs123 glad it helped, welcome to SuperUser !